# NullPointerException problem with Scala, problem with mapping

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to map over previously joined dataset.
[This is how my DS looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8WLC.png)

```
  case class CustomerData(
                       customerId: String,
                       forename: String,
                       surname: String
                     )

  case class AccountData(
                          customerId: String,
                          accountId: String,
                          balance: Long
                        )


    val customerDS: Dataset[CustomerData] = customerDF.as[CustomerData]
    val accountDS: Dataset[AccountData] = accountDF.withColumn("balance", 'balance.cast("long")).as[AccountData]

  case class CustomerAccountClass(
                               customerId: String,
                               forename: String,
                               surname: String,
                               accountId: String,
                               balance: Long

  val customerAccountDataDS = customerDS
    .joinWith(accountDS, customerDS.col("customerId") === accountDS.col("customerId"), "left")
    .map {
     case (customer, account) => CustomerAccountClass(customer.customerId, customer.forename, customer.surname, account.accountId, account.balance)
     case (customer, null) => CustomerAccountClass(customer.customerId, customer.forename, customer.surname, "", 0)
   }
```

This is the essential part of my code.
Basically I want to create new dataset with CustomerID, name, surname, and if possible account details (account ID and balance). Unfortunately whatever I try to do I receive error "NullPointerException". Am I missing anything? I don't have any nulls in column 1, only in second one, as far as I understand my code should be sufficient. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to swap the order your cases inside `map`. As far as I know, the `(customer, account)` will also match when account is null. If you do it the other way around, the actual null-case will match first:

```
.map {
    case (customer, null) => CustomerAccountClass(customer.customerId, customer.forename, customer.surname, "", 0)
    case (customer, account) => CustomerAccountClass(customer.customerId, customer.forename, customer.surname, account.accountId, account.balance)
}
```

Comment: worked, much obliged